# Of the two proofs, which one is valid? If both are valid, which one is more elegant?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Prove that a vector space has a unique additive identity.

Proof: Let $a$ and $a^\prime$ both be additive identities over a vector space $V$. $$a^\prime = a^\prime + a \text{ (because a is an additive identity.)}$$
$$=a+a^\prime \text{ (due to commutativity)}$$
$$=a \text{ (because } a^\prime \text{ is an additive identity.)}$$
Therefore, $a^\prime=a$. $\square$

Proof 2: Let $a$ and $a^\prime$ both be additive identities over a vector space $V$. Which means, $$v+a^\prime=v \text{ and } v+a=v$$
$$v+a^\prime=v+a$$ Adding $-v$ to both sides, we get:$$a^\prime=a$$
That completes the proof. $\square$

Comment: The first one is the standard one. It is "known" to be elegant. It doesn't need to introduce a $v$ and adding $-v$ and so on. It works in general for abelian groups, not only for $(V,+)$.

Comment: The first one even uses only that $a,a'$ are *left* identities (though this is pointless for abelian groups).

Comment: As a general note, the answer may depend on how you define "vector space" in the first place. The definition I learned uses a single axiom: "A vector space is an abelian group on which a field acts" -- and at that stage one supposedly already knows (as in your proof #1) that the identity element in a group (even non-abelian) is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second proof is technically invalid because you did not explain what $v$ is. Is the equation you are writing valid for *all* values of $v$? For just some? For one particular?

The first proof is short, to the point, and well justified in every step. I would even go so far as to call it elegant.

Comment: Would it be valid if I add let $v \in V$.

Comment: @KidusAyalew It would. But it would still be less elegant than the first :)